# Can i use lapply with saveRDS to save multiple files?

Tags: r

I am wondering if somebody can help...i am trying to save multiple .csv files as multiple .rds files but am getting an .rds file that is NULL

I have multiple .csv files in my working directory which i want to import as .csv and export as .rds files and have tried running the following code with lapply

```
myfiles<- list.files(patt="csv")
names(myfiles)<-myfiles

lapply(myfiles, function(x){
    a<-read.csv(x)
    saveRDS(x,file=gsub("csv","rds",x))
    })
```

Can anybody suggest where i am going wrong?

Thanks

A

Comment: You are not using the intermediate table `a` in the second line of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the table, not its name. So instead of

```
saveRDS(x,file=gsub("csv","rds",x))
```

you should have

```
saveRDS(a,file=gsub("csv","rds",x))
```

Comment: daft mistake on my end! thank you!